# Detecting PDF Download

Tags: download, spinner

I have recently added functionality for generating pdf reports to a web application. However the reports can be quite large and take some time to show the pdf download dialog. I want to show a spinner until the report is ready but have no way of knowing when the dialog appears.

any suggestions would be much appreciated.
thanks,
shawn

Comment: What language, framework, platform...?

Comment: asp.net and c#. Sorry about that guys

Comment: so how did you do it?  I have the same usecase.